# How to hide/add button depending on the place of navigation using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap dialog button, when clicked navigates t a certain url page. That page has certain elements ( for ex) that is conditionally shown depending from where it was navigated from. In short im trying to use an existing template to show/hide and add button, depending on the 'where' navigation.

For Ex: On click of the button from the dialog message,

```
$("#alert-proceed-button").on("click", function(){
    window.location.href= '#accounts/admin';
 }
```

it navigates to a url containing the following `<div>`:

```
 <div id="account">
                <button class="save-changes">Save changes</button>
 </div>
```

and that url contains the following  on that page. now when i navigate from elsewhere, i'd like to show the `<button class="save-changes">Save changes</button>`button, however when i navigate from the dialog message (i.e. `<button id="alert-proceed-button"/>`, i'd like to hide the 'Save Changes' button and append/add a new 'Add Service' button in its place:

```
 <div id="account">
                <button class="add-service">Add Service</button>
 </div>
```

Is this possible? Any ideas on how this can be done??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send both on the page and set the css display attribute of one to be hidden. Then you can use jQuery to switch that. You can check the event object to see if where it came from, so it only switches them when it originates from the alert-proceed-button.

```
function toggleSave () {
  $('.save-changes').attr('display', 'none')
  $('.add-service').attr('display', 'block')
}
```

Assuming you already have a listener on the click event for links on your page add this line:

```
if (e.target.id === 'alert-proceed-button) {
  togglesave()
}
```

Comment: so this is what i tried and it gave me "undefined". plz let me know if this is correct way. onclick of the button, i navigated to the url "#accounts/admin" and there is the function, i put this: "(e.target.id === 'alert-proceed-button)", which gave me undefined. so my guess, after i navigate to the url to the page, the id of the click event is gone and hence giving "undefined"..plz correct if im doing the wrong way..thx